# throw new \Exception no PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde , estou tendo problemas com um script

```
switch($engine) {
        case "asterisk":
            if(method_exists($core_conf, "addRtpAdditional")) {
                $core_conf->addRtpAdditional('general', array("icesupport" => "yes"));
            } else {
                throw new \Exception(_("Please update the module named 'motif' or enable the module named 'core'."));
            }
            break;
    }
```

o problema acontece neste linha aqui

```
throw new \Exception(_("Please update the module named 'motif' or enable the module named 'core'."));
```

meu servidor esta com php 5.1.6

o erro que aparece é este

```
[Wed Feb 08 16:59:18 2017] [error] [client 200.204.166.13] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /var/www/html/admin/modules/motif/functions.inc.php on line 21
```

Comment: Remove a barra do exception, deixa apenas `throw new Exception(...)`

Comment: vou tentar obrigado

Answer (score 3):

A sintaxe está errada, muda a linha para:

```
throw new Exception("Please update the module named 'motif' or enable the module named 'core'.");
```

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Apenas complementando, o caracter \ só passa a ser válido a partir da versão do PHP que implementou os namespaces (PHP 5.3.0 em diante).